# Email approval link - best way to validate the email address of the person clicking link?

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script

I am working in Google Apps, and am trying to build a workflow app which emails people a link to approve/decline requests.

I know how to capture variables from a link, however I would like to be able to capture the email address of the person who clicks the link from their inbox.  This will allow me to determine if a non-authorised person hits approve (e.g if the email is forwarded).

1. Is this possible?  My guess is not, based on other posts.
2. What other method would you suggest in this circumstance? (e.g include a link to send an email, and capture information this way)

Many thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

yew its possible but only if you can publish your script to run as the user. this will mean that:

1. any services you use must be able to run as the user, not as owner of the script (if not this can be worked arround using manual oauth2 or a 2nd worker script called from this one but its complex and out of the scope of this question)
2. the user will see an aproval screen the first time asking for permissions to such services and to view their email address.
3. the user must have a gmail/google apps email account.

with this, `session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` will give you the user's email address.

Comment: thank you @Zig Mandel for the response.  In this instance there will be approvers not using gmail so I will continue with the one-click un-authenticated approval, and if required expand to an 'email compose' type approval.